# Plugin Hooks Not Shown in WP Cron Jobs

Tags: plugins, wp-cron

I have installed a WordPress backup plug-in. This plug-in has several hooks. Some of those hooks should activate right after I trigger the backup tasks. But the problem is, after I start that plugin backup tasks, its related hooks are not shown on the WordPress Cron. As a result of that, it's not working as we expect.

Why are those hooks not registering in WordPress Cron?

Are the issues on my side or the plugin side?

Comment: which plugin? and i think the problem is in plugin

Comment: try to deactivate and then reactivate and setup a backup schedule if work, otherwise contact with developer for support.

Comment: OK Anum. But after I added it required hooks into the WP-Cron Events, it started working. Not sure how much it's correct. Because sometime after backup completed, those hooks may continuously run. Yes, I already informed it to the developer.

Comment: may be something wrong with plugin or WordPress installation.

Comment: WordPress installation? Could you please give me any clue to identify it?